# Get routes from WP

Tags: php, wordpress, routes

Hello everyone how are you?
I want to get a routes from a URL like this
domain.com/page-one/flowers
When this url open how can i get this flowers only?
I already try with this but not success. please help me for solve this. Thanks

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=properties&property_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
        );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'property_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get just the **/flowers** part only and not the change the URL?

Comment: Yes, i want want this /flowers if user input /man then i want to get /man.

Comment: So you don't want to modify the URL at all **just only to get the last part like, /flower, right?**

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is just to get the last part of the URL (eg: **flowers** from **mydomain.com/page-one/flowers**), you can just use a Filter Hook like so:

```
    <?php
        add_filter( 'page_base', 'wpGetActivePageInit', $url );

        function wpGetActivePageInit($url=null){
            $currentURL     = $url?$url:$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            $bName          = basename($currentURL);
            return $bName;
        }
```

And you could even pass null to the apply_filters Call likes so:

```
    <?php
        // CALL apply_filters WITH VALUE: [ ECHOS - flowers]
        echo apply_filters("page_base", "mydomain.com/page-one/flowers");

        // CALL apply_filters WITH NULL VALUE:  [ ECHOS THE LAST PART OF A URL LIKE: flowers IF CURRENT URL IS: mydomain.com/page-one/flowers ]
        echo apply_filters("page_base", null);
```